# Diferença no cálculo entre Excel e PHP

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Estou transformando um planilha de excel em um sistema em PHP, porém ao validar alguns valores notei que o PHP esta diferente do excel.
Tenho que fazer a seguinte conta:

- PHP (166 / 161,1) = 1,03416
- Excel (166 / 161,1) = 1,030558

Ainda tenho que multiplicar por 100 o resultado e novamente da diferente.

- PHP = 103,0
- Excel = 103,1

O Excel sempre esta arredondando isso esta gerando diferença na informação que preciso tratar.

No php já tentei as seguintes funções:

- bcdiv
- floor
- sprintf("%01.4f", (166.0/161.1));
- abs

Na calculadora do Windows retonna o mesmo valor do PHP só no excel é do contra.
Alguém já passou por isso tem alguma dica para conseguir chegar no valor igual ou mais próximo possível do excel?

Desde já agradeço a atenção e colaboração de todos.

Comment: Na minha calculadora 166÷161,1 = 1,0304158907510863. Seu Excel está interpretando a `,` corretamente?

Comment: achoq ue você transcreeu o resultado do PHP errado aí -PHP não ia dar tão fora - o resultado é 1.030415 

Melhor você colocar exatamente as expressões que está usando, em cada linguagem e ambiente, senão ninguém vai poder te ajudar: 
de o valor exato da fórmila do excel, e o código do PHP que está usando.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que seu exel esteja configurado para arredondar para cima. Existe uma função para corrigir isso segue um video https://youtu.be/eoORSGiA9es. Outra opção é arredondar no php, ai depende de qual faz mais sentido para você. Espero ter ajudado minimanete.